# Plant UML Activity Diagram, Add a partition without changing width/formatting of elements

Tags: plantuml

I have a large activity diagram with a lot of branches. I want to denote that part of this diagram is contained in one microservice, but when I add a partition it scrunches everything together and the lines get crossed, making it even more unreadable than it already was.  Is there a way around this. I searched the docs and it looks like there is no way to set the width of a partition.  While I can't post the actual code since it's confidential, here is a gibberish version

```
@startuml
skinparam backgroundColor Azure

"user clicks on link" --> "do something"

"do something" --> ===b1===
===b1=== --> "do somethin else"
===b1=== --> "yep"
"yep" --> "foobarbaz"
"do somethin else" --> "bizzfuzz"
"bizzfuzz" --> ===b2===
"foobarbaz" --> ===b2===
partition Conductor{

    if "is it it" then 
    --> ["yes it's it"] "OK"
        if "really?" then 
        -->"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
        else
        -->"asdfasdffasdfasdf"
            if "sure?" then 
            -->"zxcvzxcv"
            else
            -->"zxcv"

            endif
        endif
    else 
        -->"do something different"
        if "asdf?" then 
            -->"ghasdgf"
            else
            ->"asdf"
                if "reallysure?" then 
                -->"ireytiteryi"
                else
                -->"wertywert"
                endif
            endif
}

@enduml
```

[image: example]

Notice that if you remove the partition the elements spread out a bit. I want to keep them spread out that way but also have the partition. Is this possible? I've tried using swimlanes but it did not work for me (guess they do not work in activity diagrams)

Comment: "I've tried using swimlanes but it did not work for me (guess they do not work in activity diagrams." Swimlanes only work in the new syntax https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#dadd115c61036c7a -- your diagram is using the original syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I converted part of your diagram to swimlanes. The example with Conductor doesn't make any sense to me, so I reused something from the [PlantUML documentation with many if statements](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#9d3afea73e90192d). If you enable `!pragma userVerticalIf on`, the swimlane will become much narrower.

```
@startuml
skinparam backgroundColor Azure
!pragma useVerticalIf off
|Other|
start
:do something;
fork
:do somethin else;
:bizzfuzz;
fork again
:yep;
:foobarbaz;
end fork

|Conductor|

if (condition A) then (yes)
  :Text 1;
elseif (condition B) then (yes)
  :Text 2;
  stop
elseif (condition C) then (yes)
  :Text 3;
elseif (condition D) then (yes)
  :Text 4;
else (nothing)
  :Text else;
endif

@enduml
```

[image]